# Making a Button smaller in width

Tags: bugs, options, mac-os-x, button

I can't seem to figure out how to make the width of a `Button` smaller.

I tried change the first 26 below to a number like 10. But it doesn't seem to effect the width of the button. There seems to be a minimum size and won't let me make it any smaller. Can anyone help?

```
Button["C", Print[10!], ImageSize -> {26, 26}]
```

Comment: What is your operating system and Mathematica version? I can use any button size on Linux.

Comment: On Windows it works fine too.

Comment: This is strange.  I typed in the exact same code.  The height of my buttons change like yours but not the width.  Any ideas?

Comment: Oops missed that.  I'm running OS X 10.11.1 using Mathematica 10.3.

Comment: So I have a fix... if I change the appearance to "Palette" it works fine.  I would have it appear as a button, but this will do unless anyone has any suggestions.

Comment: I'm thinking this is a bug.  Can anyone confirm on my operating system?

Comment: Have you tried with a fresh kernel? Restarting _Mathematica_ without any user packages loaded? Are you sure you have not meddled with any system options that might affect displaying gui elements?

Comment: I do have one package running, but I don't think I changed any options.  I will try it without, and refresh the kernel and get back to you.  Thank you!

Comment: @Kuba You can confirm that the button width setting does not work?  or it work?

Comment: @MichaelMcCain good point, I can confirm the issue with fixed width on OSX 10.9

Comment: Thanks Kuba.  Then I will switch to using palette appearance.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Button Width cannot be minimized beyond a certain point when using an appearance of "Button".  Consider using the appearance of "Pallete" to get smaller widths.

Answer (score 1):

You can fake a button with a click pane, which will give complete control over appearance and has (almost) the same behavior as a button.

```
button =
  With[{size = {15, 30}},
    Graphics[
      {EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[], 
       Rectangle[{0, 0}, size, RoundingRadius -> Scaled[.2]],
       Text["C", size/2]},
      ImageSize -> size]];

ClickPane[button, Print[10!] &]
```

[image: button]

> `3628800`

Comment: The problem may be the lack of `Method` option

Comment: @Kuba. That could be a problem, but not with the example the OP gives.

Comment: Yep, just wanted to point that out.

Answer (score 0):

```
Table[Button["C", Print[10!], ImageSize -> {k, k}], {k, 10, 50, 10}]
```

Seems to work for me ! I am using 10.3

[image]

Comment: Looks like a comment not an answer.

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't see where I could upload an image inside comments.